# How to pass data from one datagrid to another,but with different number of columns

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

This is my fist time here so i'll do my best describing what's my problem:

I have one form, and on that form I have two datagrids,let's call them **dg1** and **dg2**.

**dg1** is connected to an mssql database via dataadapter,while **dg2** is not!.  Lets say I have in **dg1** information about a product:

- productID
- description
- price

In **dg2** i have something we might call bill. 
So in **dg2** i have columns

- billID
- accountnumberID
- productID
- description
- price
- Quantity

As you may predict billID is primary key, all the other one are Foreign.  Since **dg1** is filled with data from database i want when user clicks on a row in **dg1** to pass data to **dg2**, while other data from dg2 are need to be inserted somehow(that is my problem anyway). 
I have in database table bill, but i  want to pass data from one to another by `celldoubleclickevent`, and all that data to be stored in bill table in database.

```
public void loadData() 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        SqlConnection con1 = getConnection();
        con1.Open();
        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand();
        com1.Connection = con1;
        com1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        com1.CommandText = "select * from bill";
        SqlDataReader reader = com1.ExecuteReader();
        dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
        while (reader.Read()) 
        {

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false; 
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = reader["billID"].ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = reader["acountnumberID"].ToString(); 
            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = reader["productID"].ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = reader["Quantity"].ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = reader["Description"].ToString();
            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = reader["price"].ToString();
            i++; 
        }
    }
```

Thx

Comment: well i'm sorry that is complicated but it is what it is...

Comment: What is the rest of the loadData method? This method looks like it's going to load data for dg2. How is dg1 bound to it's datasource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several steps here.

First, you need to get the information from dg1.  You can do that using the `RowIndex` property of the event args, although you'll need to check that the user didn't double click a header.

```
//This will depend on how the grid is bound
var dg1ProductID = GetProductID(dg1.datasource, e.RowIndex);
```

The body of this method could be quite simple

```
private void GetProductID(Int32 RowIndex)
{
    return (Int32)(dg1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0]);
}
```

Second you'll need to put the information in dg2.

```
var newRow = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();

var bill = dataSet1.Tables[0].NewRow();
var accountNumber = GetCurrentAccountNumber();
var userQuantity = AskUserForQuantity();

dataGridView2.Rows[newRow].Cells[0].Value = -1;
dataGridView2.Rows[newRow].Cells[1].Value = accountNumber;
dataGridView2.Rows[newRow].Cells[2].Value = dg1ProductID;
dataGridView2.Rows[newRow].Cells[3].Value = userQuantity;
dataGridView2.Rows[newRow].Cells[4].Value = dg1Description;
dataGridView2.Rows[newRow].Cells[5].Value = dg1price;
```

Since the bill id is the primary key I assume it's automatically filled in.

Third you want to save the data to the bill, not sure if you want to do this in the double click event or a seperate button click event (like when the user hits `OK`).

If you are doing it in the double click then just pass the same values just added to a method to save them to the db.

```
Save(accountNumber, dg1ProductID, userQuantity, dg1Description, dg1price);
```

If not then you can enumerate the data and save from the Cell values

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow Row in dg2.Rows)
{
    if (Row.Cells[0] == -1)
    {
        Save(Row.Cells[1], Row.Cells[2], Row.Cells[3], Row.Cells[4], Row.Cells[5]);
    }
}
```

Comment: public void loadData()
        {



                try
                {
                    SqlConnection con1 = getConnection();
                    con1.Open();
                    SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand();
                    com1.Connection = con1;
                    com1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    com1.CommandText = "select *  from bill";
                   

                    SqlDataReader reader = com1.ExecuteReader();



                    dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();

Comment: i'm sorry...telephone ring yesterday all day long in my company and i couldn't give you the right anser:

Comment: while (reader.Read())
{dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = reader["billID"].ToString(); dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = reader["acountnumberID"].ToString();
                        dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = reader["productID"].ToString();dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = reader["Quantity"].ToString();dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = reader["Description"].ToString();dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = reader["price"].ToString();i++;

Comment: thank you @JamesB,your help was much appreciated,i manage to solve my problem with your assistance!

Comment: @BaneSekulic No problem Bane, glad I could help. Careful how you ask questions, a clear question is much more likely to be answered.